# WPFでの表の動的レイアウト生成の方法について

Tags: c#, wpf

現在、社内で依頼されて、C#のWPFで一覧にチェック入れて保存する画面を作成しています。
WPFは初めてなのですが、調べながらすすめています。
イベントハンドリングやDBへの登録の仕組みは作ることができました。

しかし、動的レイアウトで画面に記載した赤枠内の１段２段構成の表が動的に作成できません。（静的でもうまくいきません）

GRIDを作成して、行を追加するプログラム（RowDefinitions.Add）を組めば、赤枠の中が１セットで次々連続になることはわかっています。

このレイアウト部分について、どのように書けばいいのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問するときは環境に関する情報を詳しく記述しましょう。

- [技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](https://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#env)

まずはVisual Studioのバージョンや、ターゲットフレームワークのバージョン (.NET Frameworkまたは.NET Coreのバージョン) を提示してください。バージョンによって利用できる機能が変わるため、回答も変わる可能性があります。

ひとまずVisual Studio 2015以降、.NET Framework 4.5以降の環境であると仮定します。

テーブル内のすべてのレコードについて、カラムの数と種別が同じなのであれば、
わざわざ[Grid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid)を使うまでもなく、[ListView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview)を使って[GridViewColumn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn)の`Header`と`CellTemplate`を指定すればよいと思います。

また、WPFではデータバインディングを使い、MVVMパターンで実装するのがセオリーです。
[INotifyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged)インターフェイスを実装することで双方向バインディングもできます。
双方向バインディングでは、バインディングターゲット (View) への操作がバインディングソース (ViewModel) に直接反映され、またバインディングソースへの操作がバインディングターゲットに直接反映されるので、コードビハインドで個々の[Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control)や[UIElement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement)を操作するコードを書く必要がありません。

MVVM実装を簡素化する[Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/index.html)などの外部フレームワークもありますが、とりあえず標準ライブラリのみを使用したオーソドックスなコードを書いておきます。

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="550" Height="350"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        >
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="チェック表:"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="要約" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Summary}">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="チェック時刻">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=CheckedDateTime, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="チェック内容1">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsItem1Checked}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="チェック内容2">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsItem2Checked}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="チェック内容3">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsItem3Checked}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="チェック内容4">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsItem4Checked}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" CanVerticallyScroll="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" x:Name="buttonRegister" Content="登録" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="15,0" Click="buttonRegister_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // バインディングソースの作成。
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                var obj = new MyViewModel() { Summary = $"{i} についての確認" };
                _viewModel.Add(obj);
            }

            // バインディングソースの設定。
            // ItemsSource に対応する。
            this.listView1.DataContext = _viewModel;
        }

        private readonly ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> _viewModel = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();

        private static string ToYorN(bool x)
        {
            return x ? "Y" : "N";
        }

        private void buttonRegister_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // テスト。
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var obj in _viewModel)
            {
                string line = $"{obj.Summary}: Time={obj.CheckedDateTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}, #1={ToYorN(obj.IsItem1Checked)}, #2={ToYorN(obj.IsItem2Checked)}, #3={ToYorN(obj.IsItem3Checked)}, #4={ToYorN(obj.IsItem4Checked)}";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
                sb.Append(line);
                sb.Append("\n");
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _summary = "";
        private DateTime _checkedDateTime = new DateTime();
        private bool _isItem1Checked = false;
        private bool _isItem2Checked = false;
        private bool _isItem3Checked = false;
        private bool _isItem4Checked = false;

        public string Summary
        {
            get { return _summary; }
            set
            {
                _summary = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public DateTime CheckedDateTime
        {
            get { return _checkedDateTime; }
            set
            {
                _checkedDateTime = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsItem1Checked
        {
            get { return _isItem1Checked; }
            set
            {
                _isItem1Checked = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsItem2Checked
        {
            get { return _isItem2Checked; }
            set
            {
                _isItem2Checked = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsItem3Checked
        {
            get { return _isItem3Checked; }
            set
            {
                _isItem3Checked = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsItem4Checked
        {
            get { return _isItem4Checked; }
            set
            {
                _isItem4Checked = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

もしレコードごとにチェックボックスの説明テキストを変えたいのであれば、例えばViewModelクラスに`string`型のプロパティ (`Item1Description`, `Item2Description`, ...) を別途用意して、[CheckBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.checkbox)の`Content`プロパティにバインディングするなどの方法があります。
あとは自分で応用してください。